# SQL запрос из трех таблиц без повторов

Tags: sql, access

Есть три таблицы вида с полями

```
qselFoldersSyst:

fldrFolder

qfltOutPostavshiki:

 outFolder 
 outSendDate

qfltInPostavshiki:

 inFolder
 inArrivalDate
```

Есть запрос вида

`SELECT qselFoldersSyst.fldrFolder, qfltOutPostavshiki.outSendDate, qfltInPostavshiki.inArrivalDate FROM (qselFoldersSyst INNER JOIN qfltOutPostavshiki ON qselFoldersSyst.fldrFolder = qfltOutPostavshiki.outFolder) INNER JOIN qfltInPostavshiki ON qselFoldersSyst.fldrFolder = qfltInPostavshiki.inFolder GROUP BY qselFoldersSyst.fldrFolder, qfltOutPostavshiki.outSendDate, qfltInPostavshiki.inArrivalDate HAVING (((qselFoldersSyst.fldrFolder)=1032)) ORDER BY qfltOutPostavshiki.outSendDate, qfltInPostavshiki.inArrivalDate;`

Соответственно при таком запросе получается табличка вида

```
fldrFolder  outSendDate inArrivalDate

1032            19.03.2020  29.06.2020
1032            19.03.2020  11.08.2020
1032            19.03.2020  26.11.2020
1032            08.07.2020  29.06.2020
1032            08.07.2020  11.08.2020
1032            08.07.2020  26.11.2020
1032            31.08.2020  29.06.2020
1032            31.08.2020  11.08.2020
1032            31.08.2020  26.11.2020`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а нужно в виде

```
19,03,2020          29,06,2020  
08,07,2020          11,08,2020  
31,08,2020          26,11,2020
```

Подскажите как правильно составить запрос ?

Comment: Почему `19,03,2020` должен быть в одной итоговой записи именно с `29,06,2020`? а не с каким-то другим значением?

Comment: Да, тут жестокий затуп с моей стороны, я думал как то можно решить такую постановку задачи и забылся как правильно делаются базы данных

Comment: Можно, можно. Например, можно перенумеровать записи в порядке возрастания дат, и объединять записи с равным номером. Можно измыслить и другие критерии. Но это - вопрос логики предметной области, т.е. за пределами программирования.